# Sum incremented series of numbers like: 2+22+222+2222

Tags: python, loops

```
number_of_terms = 5
sum1=0
for i in range (1,number_of_terms+1):
    num=eval('2'*i)
    sum1+=num
print(sum1)
```

So the code given above is working.Process is like 2+22+222+2222+....n times.I couldn's solve it with different approach so I used `eval()` function but I'm trying to avoid from using it . Can you show me how can i do that without `eval()`?
Expected output with `number_of_terms` 5 is 24690.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` with *nested list comprehensions* as:

```
n = 2  # one digit number for usage
count = 5  # count of numbers required from series

my_sum = sum(sum(n*10**j for j in range(i)) for i in range(1, count+1))
# my_sum holds: 24690
```

It is based on arithmetic calculation, and doesn't require type-casting from string to int, so is more performance efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `eval`, just use `int`:

```
number_of_terms = 5
sum1=0
for i in range (1, number_of_terms + 1):
    sum1 += int('2' * i)
print(sum1)
```

Or you could just do a generator as follows:

```
print(sum(int('2' * (i + 1)) for i in range(number_of_terms)))
```

Both codes output:

```
24690
```